# Notification API pointer mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, cursor

For an intranet web app, I'm using the [notification Api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification/onclick), working great on Chrome and Firefox.
All my notifications are clickable, and redirect to specific urls.

When hovering the notification, i would like to have a pointer cursor, to ensure the user he can click on the notification.

Google search were unsuccessful :'(

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yeah, but where? :) I dont have access to the notification element template.

Comment: you don't have css? try to add: **element.style.cursor="pointer"**

Comment: I mean, which element? the notification is created by calling in js :  var notification = new Notification('...'). I don't see the element template.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do it.
You can not use CSS or any styling in a notification element: It's not part of the page.
The only thing you can do is to detect clicks, add images, title & a body.